# Did Finish Launching Notification Not Observed in View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This ViewController is the first that appears when the application launches and should call authenticateUser() when it does, but the function does not get called at all. Identical code worked correctly in a previous project of mine, but not here. Do I need to add/change more code in this new version of Swift?

class FormsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.authenticateUser), name: UIApplication.didFinishLaunchingNotification, object: nil)

}

@objc func authenticateUser() {
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).authenticateUserIfNecessary()
}
```

}

Comment: you must post  authenticateUser Notification to call authenticateUser functions show me all your code to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely that you have a race condition. Why don't you test this by adding a print statement or a breakpoint inside of your `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunching` and your VC's `viewDidLoad` to check the order. You could be attaching to `NotificantionCenter` after the notification has already been sent.